# Using find with multiple options for attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I have a web app in React where I made a search feature that uses a simple REST API in my backend where I pass in a object into Mongo's *find* function to search my database and return the results.

The objects are currently formatted like:

```
{
    attribute1: { $regex: <searchTerm1>, $options: 'i' };
    attribute2: { $regex: <searchTerm2>, $options: 'i' };
    attribute3: { $regex: <searchTerm3>, $options: 'i' };
}
```

This returns all of the documents in my database where attribute1 contains searchTerm1, attribute2 contains searchTerm2, etc. So far this part works fine and I'm able to search through my attributes.

What I now want to do is the ability to for users to select multiple options and search through them. For example a user could enter searchTerm1 and searchTerm2 for attribute1 and searchTerm3 for attribute2 and it would return every document that contains searchTerm1 *or* searchTerm2 in attribute1 *and* searchTerm3 for attribute2. I haven't been able to find a way to do this yet.

What I'm currently doing is making an array with the search terms for each attribute in my frontend but I'm not sure how to do the backend portion where I actually input all of those terms into mongoose and do the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I just had to or my search terms in the string like:

```
attribute1: { $regex: "<searchTerm1>|<searchTerm2>|<searchTerm3>", $options: 'i' };
```

This would find entries in the database that have attribute1 containing searchTerm1, searchTerm2, or searchTerm3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on--

> it would return every document that contains searchTerm1 or
>   searchTerm2 in attribute1 and searchTerm3 for attribute2

the relevant solution would be using $and and $or like -

```
{$and: [{searchTerm3}, {$or: [searchTerm1, searchTerm2]}]}
```

Comment: How would I specify the attributes with that? In that example I gave, I want searchTerm3 to specifically be for attribute2, and searchTerm1/searchTerm2 for attribute1.

Comment: This is pretty late but I figured it out. You can't use the $or operator with strings apparently but just using an or directly in my regex string solved it. See my answer for example.